# show/hide div with slide left\right animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/1/ but it does not work.
It only works if I use `show("slow")`/`hide("slow")`.

Thanks.

Comment: why you've used same `id` for multiple element? absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While not the sharpest animation, I have enabled it to behave the way I think you're wanting by finding the parent and hiding all the siblings. I'm not sure yet why this slides the elements out to the left whereas a direct call to `.siblings()` doesn't seem to.

[Seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/10/).

As others have mentioned, using classes to identify a group of items is the correct approach instead of by ID.

**Update**:

While I'm still not sure why siblings() doesn't find the siblings to the div you've found by ID, I'm suspecting it has to do something with the process of showing / hiding or possibly even using the sliding animation. Here is my suggested jQuery/jQueryUI:

```
$('a.view-list-item').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $("#"+divname).parent().siblings(":visible").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

Here is the [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/13/).

**Update**:

An [excellent update](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/15/) to the solution by @jesus.tesh

**Update**:

A [behavior update](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinjulius/CgM3x/) to the solution by @erwinjulius.
I changed DIVs positioning so it behaves better, allowing user to click on links quickly without breaking the animation.
Added white background and left-padding just for better effect presentation.

Comment: @user1453918; I'm glad it looks like it will work for you. I've updated my suggestion which might improve the user-friendliness of it. Feel free to accept this answer if it does answer your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, surely I will use the latest version of yourscript! ;)

Comment: I modified the fiddle to make the animation a bit smoother: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/15/) - just another option for you.

Comment: Just to clarify, looks like the .show("slide") function requires jQuery UI

Comment: This is for JQuery <= 1.7.2  only, Jquery 2 don't run

Answer (score 1):

However, this codes works, the name tag in elements is obsolete to W3C standards.

I tried with ID's does not work, then I changed the name tag to the title and this works too and you comply with W3C standards!

So change "name" to "title" like this, it functions great, sees here: http://design65grafischontwerp.nl/#portfolio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            var divtitle = this.title;
            $("#" + divtitle).show("slow").siblings().hide(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```