# jQuery animate horizontally not vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2  tags with content, a left and right pane. When you click a button I need the left pane to disappear. this is simple and I do this:

```
$("#leftPanel").hide(800);
```

Works fine,  however, the content in the left pane hides vertically, THEN the right pane slides over horizontally.

How do I get it to just hide itself horizontally?

Comment: Please post a complete example

Comment: Also fiddle can be good option.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017332/show-hide-div-with-slide-left-right-animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hide` method can accept an easing effect, its customization and a duration.

You can mix them to have a similar graphical behavior by sliding in left direction

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Code:

```
$("#hideme").click(function () {
    $(".obj2").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 800);
});

$("#showme").click(function () {
    $(".obj2").show('slide', '', 800);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/veER4/

Answer (score 3):

You should look at jQuery's native animate function:

```
// Slide closed and hide
$('#element').animate({
    width: '0px' // no width
}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

// Show and slide back open
$('#element').show().animate({
    width: '100px' // full width in pixels
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery UI effects for that

http://jqueryui.com/hide/

Try the hide slide effect.

```
$("#leftPanel").hide("slide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the translation with css using `transform: translateX()`

example:

```
element{
/* Start hidden */
transition: 0.5s;
transform: translateX(110%);}

element.active{
/* Showing the element */
transition: 0.5s;
transform: translateX(0%);}
```

and on the click event in javascript you toggle the active class