# How to hide my sliding side nav when i click elsewere?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to mimic android's side menu style. here is the link to my codepen 
https://codepen.io/Killerbee98/pen/KqreZw.
My problem is that it doesn't close when i press outside of the navigation as it does on android. Now i have done some research on how to do smth like this; first would be to use:

```
$('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

but this isn't a practical method and is wrong to use.

Second would be to add a click listener using :

```
$(document).click(function(event){ 
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
    $('.navigation').hide();
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work with my code since my code has a click listener:

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
   console.log("button pressed");
   if($('.navigation').width() === 250){
   $('.navigation').width('0px');
}else{
   $('.navigation').width('250px');
  }
})
```

i tried doing this:

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
   console.log("button pressed");
   if($('.navigation').width() === 250){
   $('.navigation').width('0px');
   $(document).click(function(event){ 
       if (!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
           $('.navigation').hide();
       }
   });
 }else{
   $('.navigation').width('250px');
  }
})
```

it closes but doesn't open back again as it should.

how do i go about solving my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: @Kukic Vladimir i know and have read those posts but i want to avoid using the stopPropagation method. What you answered worked for me and i have done it but any other way without using the mentiond event method?

Comment: did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/2744511) on the same post. People are saying that it working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have managed to make a working example by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/3028037#3028037)

Here is the code

```
 $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
     if($('.navigation').is(":visible")) {
            $('.navigation').hide();
        } else {
           $('.navigation').show();
        }
})

$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length &&      
    !$(event.target).hasClass('menu-btn')) {
        if($('.navigation').is(":visible")) {
            $('.navigation').hide();
        }
    }        
})
```

EDIT:

Also I Have adjusted css style for `navigation` class

```
.navigation{
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 15px 0px #999;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/29xr46zk/)

Comment: it's not loading for some reason... it keeps on refreshing!

Comment: @Killerbee89 let me edit the answer with code snippet from fiddle

Comment: @Killerbee89 here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/29xr46zk/) i have updated answer link as well

Comment: it works great but then i lose the animation wich is important

Comment: @Killerbee89 you can achieve that effect by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017332/show-hide-div-with-slide-left-right-animation) which uses `jQuery UI`,

Answer (score 0):

The only changes you need to your EXISTING code is to add the same styles for both the `button` `click` event and the `document` `click` event.

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("button pressed");
  if ($('.navigation').width() === 250) {
    $('.navigation').hide();
    $('.navigation').width('0px');
  } else {
    $('.navigation').show();
    $('.navigation').width('250px');
  }
})
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
    $('.navigation').hide();
    $('.navigation').width('0px');
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 15px 0px #999;
  transition: .2s;
  display: none;
}

.header-image {
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content="";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}

.bar:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.bar:after {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-btn">
  <span class="bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="header-image"></div>
  <ul>
    <div class="link">
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation(); works without anything extra... the challenge is not to use it and still be able to have animation. @Kukic Vladimir's code works great but at the cost of losing the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kukic Vladimir's solution, it works with a bit of change in the JS code he provided.

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
 if($('.navigation').width() === 0) {
        $('.navigation').width('250px');
    } else {
       $('.navigation').width('0px');
    }
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length &&      
!$(event.target).hasClass('menu-btn')) {
    if($('.navigation').width('250px')) {
        $('.navigation').width('0px');
    }
 }        
})
```